# preset-env and core-js don't seem to use browserslist

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Using the [official docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html) I've been trying to setup an optimal build config using: `@babel/preset-env` and `core-js` with a `.browserslist` file.

As far as I understand the docs, they say that `preset-env` with `useBuiltins:"usage"` will update the `import 'core-js/stable'` statement in my code, to only include the required functions.

However, no matter if I set `last 1 chrome version` or `>1% in NL` (which are considerably more and older browsers), the build file is the same size (about 3MB).

[image: webpack bundle size]

What am I missing?

I have a test repo available here: https://github.com/publicJorn/jorns-react-starter

For quick reference, the relevant files:

**.babelrc**

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": { "version": 3, "proposals": true }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
    ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
    ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
  ]
}
```

**webpack part**

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
```

**.browserslistrc**

```
> 1% in NL
ie 11
not ie < 11
```

**index.js**

```js
import 'core-js/stable'

// etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

If propertie `useBuiltIns` was `usage`, core-js will bundle polyfill code what you are using in project.

If `useBuiltIns` was `entry`, it will bundle polyfill code by browserslist setting. don't forget import core-js manually.

```js
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

---

Now, `usage` and `entry` are both bundle polyfill by browser setting above `@babel/core>=7.18`